# Make possible to get rejected value

Tags: node.js

I hope someone can help me out with my issue to get back the reject value out of this functions:

```
        (async () => {
            await queue.add(() => startCompare(orgpath, dpath, xray));
            console.log('done compare ' + entry);
        })();
```

This call the function:

```
async function startCompare(orgFile, compFile, xFile)
{
    let gstderr;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        spawn('compare', [orgFile, compFile, '-metric', 'AE', 'null:'])
            .progress(function (childProcess) {

                childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                    console.log('[spawn] stdout: ', data.toString());
                });
                childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
                    gstderr =  data.toString();
                    console.log('[spawn] stderr: ', data.toString());
                });

            }).then(res => {

                resolve(true);

            }).catch(error => {

                resolve(gstderr);

            });
    });
}
```

My goal is how to get back gstderr value when rejected. Maybe the arrow function is the wrong way? I want to print out the value at: `console.log('done compare ' + entry + xxxxx);` where xxxxx is the rejected value.

Comment: maybe you should replace resolve(gstderr) inside catch with reject(gstderr) and then try  @Rafael Rocha answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the rejected value of a promise with `async/await` by using `try/catch` like so:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    // if it gets resolved lands here
    const result = await startCompare(...args)
    console.log(result) // should be true

  } catch(error) {
   // if it gets rejected it lands here
   console.log(error) // should be the gstderr
  }
})()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Many thanks, but this just return me the pending promise, not the final result of the promise.

Comment: That sounds weird, you're calling await on the startCompare function I assume?
Then it should yield only when the promise in startCompare resolves or rejects.
Please make sure you get the value when you call .then() or catch() in the startCompare.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const canLogin = createAsyncThunk("AUTH/login", 
async (loginData ,{ rejectWithValue })=> {
    try{
        const response=await axios.post(AuthConfig.API_URL + AuthConfig.LOGIN_URI, loginData)
        return response
    }
    catch(error){
        if (!error.response || !error.message) 
            throw error
        return rejectWithValue(getErrorMessage(error))
    }    
  }
);

export function getErrorMessage(error) {
    return (
      error?.response?.data?.message ||
      error?.response?.data.error ||
      error?.response?.data ||
      error?.message ||
      error.toString()
    );
}
```